# Salesforce Bulk Api gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I have read about databasedotcom gem but it doesn't support bulk api. Are there any salesforce bulk api gem that uses Oauth2 for login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo gem install salesforce_bulk_api`
https://github.com/yatishmehta27/salesforce_bulk_api

Answer (score 0):

There's also a gem for bulk query: https://github.com/cvengros/salesforce_bulk_query